# vertical centering in pmatrix

Tags: math-mode, vertical-alignment, matrices

I have a little optical Problem with an horizontal alignment in a pmatrix. I would like to get an output like the below but the `\vdots` doesn't look nice. I would like to replace the two `\vdots` in the first and the third vector with one, vertically centered `\vdots`. I have tried a `\multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{4}{*}{\vdots}}` like I would in a table but that gave me just a weird output. I hope someone could help me since I didn't find anything in the Internet. Here's a MWE with my problem. Thanks in advance for any kind of help.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts, 
            amsmath, 
            amssymb, 
            amsthm}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
    \begin{equation*}
        e_1=\begin{pmatrix}
            1\\
            0\\
            \\
            \vdots\\
            \vdots\\
            \\
            0
        \end{pmatrix},\qquad\dots\qquad
        e_i = \begin{pmatrix}
            0\\
            \vdots\\
            0\\
            1\\
            0\\
            \vdots\\
            0
        \end{pmatrix},\qquad\dots\qquad
            e_r=\begin{pmatrix}
            0\\
            \\
            \vdots\\
            \vdots\\
            \\
            0\\
            1
        \end{pmatrix}.
    \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graphic of my problem]

Answer (score 4):

Using vertical dots that have the same height as digits, possibly.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}

\newcommand{\lowvdots}{\vphantom{0}\smash{\vdots}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
e_1=
\begin{pmatrix}
  1\\
  0\\
  \\
  \lowvdots\\
  \\
  \\
  0
\end{pmatrix},
\quad\dots\quad
e_i=
\begin{pmatrix}
  0\\
  \lowvdots\\
  0\\
  1\\
  0\\
  \lowvdots\\
  0
\end{pmatrix},
\quad\dots\quad
e_r=
\begin{pmatrix}
  0\\
   \\
   \\
  \lowvdots\\
   \\
  0\\
  1
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I dont really see the difference between in the result of `\vdots` and `\lowvdots`. But this looks better than my first solution. I'm just curious if it would look even better when the dots are centered between the to zeros or if this is the nicer solution.